# StringTokenizers for Java with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, stringtokenizer

I'm working on a project that requires users input 7 information elements (all at once, separated by commas). If any invalid fields entered, display an message and ask user to input that field again. If all the info. entered correctly. Display all the fields, one field per line with label. Here what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Implementation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter first name: ");
        String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter last name: ");
        String lastName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter address: ");
        String address = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter city: ");
        String city = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter state: ");
        String state = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter zipcode: ");
        String zip = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter phone: ");
        String phone = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nValidate Result:");

        if (!validateFirstName(firstName))
            System.out.println("Invalid first name");
        else if (!validateLastName(lastName))
            System.out.println("Invalid last name");
        else if (!validateAddress(address))
            System.out.println("Invalid address");
        else if (!valiadteCity(city))
            System.out.println("Invalid city");
        else if (!validateState(state))
            System.out.println("Invalid state");
        else if (!validateZip(zip))
            System.out.println("Invalid zipcode ");
        else if (!validatePhone(phone))
            System.out.println("Invalid phone");
        else
            System.out.println("Valid input. Thank you!");
    }
    public static boolean validateFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        return firstName.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*");
    }        
    public static boolean validateLastName(String lastName)
    {
        return lastName.matches("[a-zA-z]+(['-][a-zA-Z]+)*");
    }
    public static boolean validateAddress(String address)
    {
        return address.matches("\\d+\\s+([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+)");
    }        
    public static boolean valiadteCity(String city)
    {
        return city.matches("([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+)");
    }        
    public static boolean validateState(String state)
    {
        return state.matches("([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+)");
    }        
    public static boolean validateZip(String zip)
    {
        return zip.matches("\\d{5}");
    }        
    public static boolean validatePhone(String phone)
    {
        return phone.matches("[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java and I do not really know what to do for StringTokenizers. The code above I used basic input. However, I wrote a little part for that but do not sure and no idea where to put it.

```
System.out.println("Enter info. separated by comma: ");
String sentence = scanner.nextLine();

String[] tokens = sentence.split(",");
System.out.printf("Number of elements: %d%nThe tokens are:%n", tokens.length);

for (String token : tokens)
    System.out.println(token);
```

I came up with two problems:

> 1. I do not know where/how to do `StringTokenizers` on my code.
> 2. How do I display all the fields if info entered correctly?

**It would be nice if you can explain right on my code. Because I'm new and not really sure what to do. Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer uses for splitting the input string into tokens using the specified separator.
For such kind of tasks where you know the sequence of the elements and for each of the elements there are predefined validation I would prefer to avoid using loops.

The main idea of the tasks is firstly to split the input string into the array of elements and then perform validation.

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String[] elements = input.split(',');
if (elements.length != 7) { 
    System.out.println("Invalid input string");
    System.exit(0);    
}

String firstName = elements[0];
while (!validateFirstName(firstName)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter first name: ");
    firstName = scanner.nextLine();
}

String secondName = elements[1];
while (!validateSecondName(secondName)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter second name: ");
    secondName = scanner.nextLine();
}
// ... The same logic for the other fields.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm getting it but not quite sure. Let me try to work on my code then let you know if anything happens. Thank you very much!